# How to log message MQ Message before it's converted to a DTO?

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

When wiring up an existing web service to handle an MQMessage, I'd like to be able to serialize the message to a database, before it it's turned into a request object and passed to the service endpoint. How can I do that given this code in my apphost file?

```
var mqServer = container.Resolve<IMessageService>();
//todo: would like to log the message here, instead of the Service, or Global filter
mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformation>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);          
mqServer.Start();
```

**Update**

This is what I was hoping to implement

```
var mqServer = container.Resolve<IMessageService>();
mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformation>(m =>
{
    var db = container.Resolve<IFrontEndRepository>();
    db.SaveMessage(m as Message);
    return ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(m);
});          
mqServer.Start();
```

Are there any drawbacks to this?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the message in the RegisterHandler

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformation>(m =>
{
    var db = container.Resolve<IFrontEndRepository>();
    db.SaveMessage(m as Message);
    return ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(m);
});
```

Or if you prefer, using the RequestFilter:

```
mqServer.RequestFilter = m =>
{
    var db = container.Resolve<IFrontEndRepository>();
    db.SaveMessage(m as Message);
    return m;
});
```

Comment: Using AppSelfHostBase, can't seem to get the RequestFilter to compile.

Comment: If you're not using the concrete type, you'll need to cast it, e.g: `((RabbitMqServer)mqServer).RequestFilter = ...;`